# HTML5 Canvas roulette wheel

Tags: html, canvas

I have built a roulette wheel in canvas and JS.
The wheel has 12 segments which are 30 degrees wide.

I would like it so that when the wheel rotates past a wheel segment, a sound is played.
I have tried to use modulus but could not get it working. Any tips or advice?

```
if (rotation % 30 == 0) {
    playSound();
}
```

Comment: Is your rotation in degree ? Then why % and not > ?

Comment: Do you have a link to your roulette wheel? I'm trying to build one as well.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing your rotation in is degree, you probably want

```
if (((rotation+360)%360)<30) {
```

This starts by computing an angle between 0 and 360.

If you angle is in radian, which is the native unit of Canvas, you might do

```
 if (((rotation+2*Math.PI)%(2*Math.PI))<Math.PI/6) {
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely wrong. I would rephrase the problem of the OP. So there are 12 segments. And the sound must be played, whenever wheel passes a segment. So if the previous rotation was in 16deg, and the current is in 66deg( depends on angular-speed), then 2 sounds should be played, as there are 2 segments(in 30deg and in 60deg), that wheel had passed.

Comment: @Engineer. You obviously don't understand the question in the same manner than me. Why don't you make an answer ?